# what is the angular way of opening a popup help window for a form field

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, popupwindow

Perhaps Angular has a built-in way of doing this?  But if not, let's say that either the label for a form field is clickable, or a button next to the field is.  What would the Angular way be to open a window displaying help relevant to the particular form input?

How does the name of the field or of the label get passed to the popup window so it can fetch the appropriate help content from a local array, say (not ajax)? Alternatively, how does the click handler fetch the content and pass it to the window?

These things are easy-peasy if done in javascript directly, or if jQuery opens a popup window in the click handler; but how to do this common task "the Angular way" is not clear to me. How do the window and the click on the label/button get "wired up"?

Let's assume the label wraps the input:

```
         <label for="foo" > <input></input>< /label>
```

Extra points for simplicity!

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover not good for that?

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: I suggest you to write a directive for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular-ui-bootstarp tooltip :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <label for="input_{{$index}}">{{field.label}}:</label>
      <input type="text" id="input_{{$index}}" tooltip="{{field.tooltip}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

OR

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <label for="input_{{$index}}">{{field.label}}:</label>
      <input type="text" id="input_{{$index}}" tooltip="{{getTooltip($index)}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

JS file:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var app = angular.module('plunker');
var fields = [
  {label:'name',tooltip:'enter your name here'},
  {label:'Age',tooltip:'enter your Age here'},
  {label:'Gender',tooltip:'enter your gender here'}

];
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.fields= fields;

$scope.getTooltip=function(index){
return fields[index].tooltip;
}


});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/R0d1aCEbZjr6003y6ehV?p=preview

Comment: But I would like not to have to create a separate $scope variable for each tooltip, but instead to have the content determined by some parameter. How to pass that parameter to a function that displays the tooltip with dynamically-chosen content, based on that parameter? For example, I have all of my tooltip text content in an object array, where the keys are fieldnames.

Comment: I updated the the plunker sample tooltips are read from an array

Comment: So, even though the `id` is a string literal, `id="input_$index"`,  `$index` is treated as a variable, and its value changes with each iteration of `ng-repeat`?

Comment: sorry it should be id="input_{{$index}}" and yes it will treated as a variable 0-based , check the updated link from pluncker

Comment: and you can add a function in the $scope that take argument like $index , eg tooltip="{{yourfunction($index)}}"